# Print full array items with Visual Studio Code

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

[image]

I use Visual Studio Code and I want to print all of the array data, but it only shows ... more items message.
Is there any ways to show it all?
I search it on stackoverflow but I can't find the solution.

I user default cmd terminal and it runs with Node.js

Comment: What command did you use to get the result shown in the question?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I use node app.js command with CMD in Vscode terminal :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be trying iterate over every element inside the array and printing then individually. See the code below:

```
arr = [2, 54, 72, ... ] // your big array
arr.forEach(e => console.log(e))
```

See also https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-foreach-function/ where above code was taken

Comment: I have this same issue and am just printing an array without iteration. Just console.log(arr). And in VS Code default terminal I get the elements of the array up to a point and then "... X more items"

Comment: Update: this happens in Windows default command terminal as well, so it's not a VS Code issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can stringify the array and print it, just like a json object.

You can do something like

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
```

This will print the stringified version of the array which can be beautified in any editor